# Microsoft speech to text is not identifying other than english language

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am using microsoft speech to text service. my requirement is to identify and convert any spoken language on microphone should converted on text . example if i speak spanish then i should get spanish language text as response.

here is my code and am setting config by providing subscription key and endpoint url

```
  var config = SpeechConfig.FromHost(new Uri("ws://xxxxxxxx:5000/"));

    using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Say something...");
        var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();

        // Checks result.
        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"We recognized: {result.Text}");
        }
    }
```

Please help me how to get converted any speech to text languages.

Answer (score 0):

A common task for speech recognition is specifying the input (or source) language. Let's take a look at how you would change the input language to German. In your code, find your SpeechConfig, then add this line directly below it.

```
speech_config.speech_recognition_language="de-DE"
```

speech_recognition_language is a parameter that takes a string as an argument. You can provide any value in the list of supported locales/languages.

Please use the locale in the table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#speech-to-text

-Yutong

Comment: Thank you. do we have any privillage in MS speech service that if user speaks system autometically identifies the language spoken without explicilty setting up the speech_recognition_language="lang iso code"

Comment: Hello, you can use the language identification. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-automatic-language-detection?pivots=programming-language-csharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use language detection in the Speech Recognizer processing, see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-automatic-language-detection?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

It has some limitations in terms of languages (see language support [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#speech-to-text)).

### How?

For a C# implementation, you should switch "Latency" to "Accuracy" depending on priority on the speechConfig object:

```
speechConfig.SetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_SingleLanguageIdPriority, "Latency");
```

Add an `AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig` config to your `SpeechRecognizer`:

Then you can have your result:

```
var autoDetectSourceLanguageConfig =
    AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig.FromLanguages(
        new string[] { "en-US", "de-DE", "ja-JP", "de-DE" });

using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(
    speechConfig,
    autoDetectSourceLanguageConfig,
    audioConfig))
{
    var speechRecognitionResult = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
    var autoDetectSourceLanguageResult =
        AutoDetectSourceLanguageResult.FromResult(speechRecognitionResult);
    var detectedLanguage = autoDetectSourceLanguageResult.Language;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem which autodetectsourcelanguageconfig does not work, but this method work for me.

```
var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxx", "xxx");
    config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "ja-JP";
```